# $_POST on a While loop?

Tags: php, mysql, forms, post, http-post

my question is: can you POST using a form and a  inside a while loop? I have this from that is supposed to give me a check box and the titles of songs next to it, i want to be able to select a few check boxes and post them to a "process.php" but this code i made is not posting anything to the process.php. if i click the submit button without checking any boxes it defaults to the last result # in my database, if i check any or a few boxes it says its "undifined off-set # 9" which is the last result in my database. if i make the form inside the while loop i get a ton of submit buttons per result. I am not sure what im doing wrong! please help me!!!

This is what i need to happen 
⎕ song name
⎕ song name two
SUBMIT

if you click submit the on process.php i should be able to use the "song_name"

```
Please select songs: <br>


            <form method="post" action="process.php">
            <?php 
            $servername = "localhost";
            $username = "root";
            $password = "";
            $dbname = "song_selection";

            // Create connection
            $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
            // Check connection
            if ($conn->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
            } 

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM songs";
            $result = $conn->query($sql);

            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            $a = 1;

            // output data of each row
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $song_name = $a++;
            //echo "title: " . $row["title"]. "<br>";
            ?>
            <div width="200">


            <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="<?php echo $song_name; ?>" value="<?php echo $song_name; ?>" id="CheckboxGroup1_0" />
            <?php echo $row['title']; ?></label>



            </div>
            <?php
            } echo '<input type="submit" value="thanks">';
            } else {
            echo "0 results";
            }

            ?>

            </form>

            <?php 
            echo $_POST[$song_name];
            ?>
```

Comment: Try adding a action to your <form action='' method='post'>

Comment: @Zapp hi thanks for pointing that out, I did include the action on the form previously but it had the same result, it appears the $_post isn't carrying over somehow. I suspect is because the loop but I'm not sure.

Comment: How did you process the form in **process.php** page? Update your question with the relevant code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$song_name` is a counter value, not the actual song name, and you used it in `value=""` attribute. I believe `$row['title']` is the actual song name, so replace,

```
<input type="checkbox" name="<?php echo $song_name; ?>" value="<?php echo $song_name; ?>" id="CheckboxGroup1_0" />
```

with

```
<input type="checkbox" name="<?php echo $song_name; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['title']; ?>" id="CheckboxGroup1_0" />
```

**And from your question:**

> if you click submit the on process.php i should be able to use the "song_name"

If this is your requirement then process the form like this:

**process.php**

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
    echo $key . ": " . $value . "<br />";
}
```

Comment: Hi Rajdeep! Thank you so much for your help, this totally fixed my issue! I really appreciate it!